# `make4ht`, `htlatex`: calls out error when called on an absolute filepath

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

For this problem, I am using the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}
\maketitle

\section{Section One}

Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
    \begin{equation}
        x + y = 3
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I ran the following command (note periods/full-stops in the directory):

```
make4ht "A:\test_tex_sources\test_article.tex"
```

But then I get the following error:

```
> make4ht "A:\test_tex_sources\test_article.tex"
Output dir:
Compiler:       latex
Latex options:   -jobname=A:\test_tex_sources\test_article
tex4ht.sty :    xhtml,
tex4ht
build_file      A:\test_tex_sources\test_article.mk4
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param ext
Adding:         ext     dvi
LaTeX call: latex  -jobname=A:\test_tex_sources\test_article  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,.a.b.c.\input A:\test_tex_sources\test_article
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> ...keatother\HCode xhtml,.a.b.c.\input A:\test
                                                  _tex_sources\test_article
?
```

However, if I switch into the directory containing the `.tex` file, and then run:

```
make4ht test_article.tex
```

everything works okay.

What's the issue with using the absolute file path?

Comment: Changing backslashes in path onto slashes should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case switching

```
make4ht "A:\test_tex_sources\test_article.tex"
```

onto

```
make4ht "A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tex"
```

should solve the problem. Even if in an operating systems there are backslashes in a path, we change them into slashes for TeX tools.